# Raphael JS server-side

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, server-side

I'm using Raphael js to create some graphics on the client.
But I'd now like to be able to do the same thing directly on the server to be able to create them and store them in batch.

I've found solutions where the SVG form Raphael is fetched from the client, but not any completely server-side.

Does any one have experience using Raphael js server side only (with Rhino for instance)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) - it's basically a full webkit browser you can run headless from the command line and render the output to a PNG.

There is actually an example using Raphael on the [Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart) guide.

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png
```

Comment: It appears to be the best solution I found so far! Unfortunately, because of lack of time and since I need the solution to work on Solaris (I'm not sure that building webkit is simple on this OS), the issue have been postponed. But thanks anyway!